# Запрос update в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом...

Цель: Есть две таблицы с одинаковой структурой (name, isPurchased). Необходимо найти в первой таблице поля с именами втречающимися во второй и обновить у них поле isPurchased взяв его из второй таблицы.

Запрос:

```
UPDATE first SET isPurchased=(SELECT isPurchased FROM second WHERE name=first.name) WHERE isPurchased IS NULL;
```

Итого: Все пашет в SQLite administrator, но на девайсе first остается без изменений.

Comment: Код в студию. db.update() делали?

Comment: вместо него я делаю db.execSQL();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все равно по всей таблице пробегаете, то лучше сделать так:

```
UPDATE first SET isPurchased=1 WHERE name in (SELECT name FROM second WHERE isPurchased = 0);
```

Да и как указано в комментариях, вы применяете изменения к БД?